# why does my obj have differnt shades of grey on faces in object view

Tags: modeling, artifacts

Why does my object have different shades of grey on faces in *Object Mode*? It also looks and glitches when I export it to Roblox studio, and the different shades are still there even with a material or texture. I'm relatively new to Blender. How do I resolve this?

Object Mode:

[image]

Wireframe Mode:

[image]

original:

[image]

updated with edits:

[image]

Comment: are all of the points of these three faces coplanar?

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Idk what co-planar means, ill look into it

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Harry McKenzie's answer, after you have recalculated the normals, you need to flatten the faces. Select them all with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Normal* and flatten with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, it will fix the shading problem:

[image]

Comment: ty that helped with the shading too

Answer (score 1):

To see the problem, you have to enable *Face Orientation* under *Viewport Overlays* and temporarily disable the *Solidify Modifier* by disabling that monitor icon. Notice that you have inverted Face Normals as displayed as red faces. Fix them first by selecting all objects and then going into *Edit Mode* with <kbd>tab</kbd> then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces and then go to menu *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside* or use shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Also also while all faces are selected press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* to remove 5 duplicate overlapping vertices.

[image]

And then fix this [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) by either deleting the internal faces marked with a red X. And the face between and above the faces marked with a yellow X. And then fill the missing face. Then again recalculate normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Then lastly remove the Mirror Modifier for `Cylinder.002`, which you don't need, because it is causing the whole arch to overlap with the original. Or delete the other half of it before mirroring.

Comment: Thank you so much, i followed all the steps and its much better, the shading is better excpet for one square and a corner here: https://imgur.com/a/0QF94JK

i will post the updated blend file in the post